# Vue - показать/скрыть элемент, генерируемый v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Какой самый лучший в VUE способ изменять видимость div в элементе li, который генерируется v-for ? Проблема в том, что приходят на ум какие то уж очень избыточные решения, или решения из нативного js с перебором нод. Проблема в том, что все везде будет одинаковым, и при стандартном решении все li будут менять состояние одновременно.

```
 <li :key="message.id" v-for="message in getMessages" v-on:click="openMessage($event)">
                <p>{{ message.title }} ({{ message.name }}) - {{ getDate(message.created_at) }}</p>

                <div class="show">
                <p>{{ message.email }}</p>
                <p>{{ message.phone }}</p>
                <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: ```v-if="message.visible"``` например, если в visible будет храниться состояние

Comment: Данные подтягиваются с бэка на laravel. Если имеется в виду добавление еще одного поля в модель - мне это не очень нравится

Comment: А от чего зависит показывать элемент или нет?

Comment: На данный момент не от чего. Я и пытаюсь придумать условие, что бы у каждой li был свой независимый индификатор. И при этом сделать это как то более-менее не избыточно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант - хранить состояние элемента списка в его объекте. При этом нет необходимости добавлять это в передаваемые данные. Добавим свойство `hide` уже при создании страницы и так, что оно будет реактивным. Для примера элементы исчезают по клику:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list: [
      { id: 1, text: "text" },
      { id: 2, text: "another text"},
      { id: 3, text: "one more text"},
      { id: 4, text: "last text" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   change: function(id){
     this.list.forEach(i => i.id === id ? i.hide = true : true)
    }
  },
  created(){
   this.list.map(item => Vue.set(item, 'hide', false) )
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" @click="change(item.id)" v-show="!item.hide">
     {{item.text}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Так как у меня vuex пришлось повозится, но да, это работает, спасибо. Хотя возможно будет проще добавлять это поле мутатором в laravel

Comment: Как альтернативный вариант можно создавать вспомогательный объект в формате ```{id: state}``` и показывать/скрывать элементы списка основываясь на нем.